# 'grid' layout with forms in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I want to implement a 'grid' layout in my RN app, but as RN doesnt support grid style I'm confused about how can I do it.

I need to do something just like this:

[image: grid layout]

Where blue and green boxes will be text inputs (numeric only) and the red box will be a picker.

Unfortunately, css isnt my best skill.
Can anyone help me? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way would be to put a column inside a row, which you can do by using react-native stylesheet's 'flexDirection' property, like this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>    
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Input style={{flex: 1}} />
        <Input style={{flex: 1}} />
    </View>
    <Picker style={{flex: 1} />    
</View>
```

Comment: Hi Paulo, thanks for yout answer! Solved my problem :)
I was doing something really close to this, but wasnt using flex 1 in all components, thats something that I need to study more.